# Unified Aesthetics

Tags: user-experience

I've been watching Extra Credits videos to learn concepts about designing video games and [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch) especially impacted me. It made me realize that the aesthetics of a game might have even more influence on players than the mechanics.

Basically, the video explains how a visual theme that immerses a player is better than any graphically superior one that does not - and how many successful games have visuals which work together to create the same world, while less successful games fall short there.

I've just prototyped a game for iOS based on [2048](http://gabrielecirulli.github.io/2048/) and I'm not sure how to unify the aesthetics to make it more immersive for the player. In 2048, a plain board with tiles of interesting colors work well because the game is relaxing and simple but the one I'm making is fast-paced and twitchy.

Here are the [webplayer link](https://7709cfa16905944356cb65818b0169aee1f2fc08.googledrive.com/host/0B0eYzcEYIV24UWJpX0EzVnktb2M) and [some screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGE2y.jpg) which show the gist of it.

I opted for a sci-fi theme because I think it suited the fast-paced feeling of the game. I'm not so sure about the progressive colors or the cube shapes though. *Sigh*, I already see this question getting too broad - sorry I'm not very experienced with this subject.

What I'm asking specifically is for feedback concerning the visual synergy between the number cubes, obstacles, and vector grid. With these 3 elements, how can I modify, add, or remove pieces to make the world of the game seem consistent?

If you have any in mind, recommended articles or other resources about game aesthetics would be very helpful as well.

Comment: As you're very aware, this is just too much of a broad question. Aesthetics is not about a defined set of rules, and is not somethign you can learn by asking in a forum or reading one article. From the top of my head I can see that your game mixes pixel-like blockiness, gradients, semitransparency, flat backgrounds, oversaturated colors and unsaturated colors. If you want good, consistent art for -this- game, I'd recommend you find somebody with more artistic experience to help you; if you want to do it yourself, prepare to dedicate years or decades to learn art.

Comment: You're right. I was trying to solo this project which seemed like a good idea at the time until I ran until the intangibles of art.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Panda Pajama is definitely correct about having to take the time and possibly money to learn a depth knowledge of art. But, it really can depend on the complexity of your game. You will have to oversimplify things if you don't have the art skills. Many games do this.

Here is a VERY brief and general article on some things to know when designing for aesthetics in games.
http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/185676/the_aesthetics_of_game_art_and_.php?print=1

This may be obvious, but another good way to learn is to just take a few art classes, specifically at a well rated technical game development and design school. I feel every developer should take a few art classes, it makes you a better developer because you think of these things in the back of your mind while you are programming/developing. It promotes creativity. It also saves headaches in the long run.

Good luck!